# Create equal areas with the intersection of a function with the first and fourth quadrants.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Here's a question I wasn't able to figure out in class. The first part was easy enough, but the second part stumped even my teacher as well.

"Consider the first- and fourth quadrant regions between the x-axis and f(x)=x(x-1)(x-a). What value of a makes the areas equal?(a=2)

Then find b which does it(make the areas equal) for g(x)=x(x-1)(x-b)+1"

Comment: Is the area over an interval for $x$? Otherwise, the area in the fourth quadrant is finite whereas the area in the first quadrant would be infinite as $x(x-1)(x-a) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.